# Is there a suitable python library for doing stream processing with Kafka topics?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, stream-processing, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to find a suitable Python library to do stream processing with streams Kafka topics, Kafka streams. Specifically, I am looking for libraries that support the following operations.

- KStream-to-Kstream
- KTable-to-Ktable
- KTable-to-KTable Foreign-Key Join
- KStream-to-KTable

as listed here https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have looked into the confluent_kafka library and kafka_python library but apart from supporting simple consumption of Kafka topics, they don't look like they have out-of-the-box support for more complex operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out [Faust](https://github.com/robinhood/faust) or [bytewax](https://github.com/bytewax/bytewax). I think either of those would allow you to do complex operations in Python like windowing, aggregations and joins in some sense.

Unfortunately, I don’t think Faust isn’t being actively maintained by Robinhood anymore.

Comment: Faust was forked to `faust/faust-streaming`